# Equivalent Capacity of a Circuit?

Tags: capacitor

[image]

Can someone explain me how to solve this case and find the equivalent capacitance?

Comment: More details on what you have tried would be helpful.  Do you mean "equivalent capacitance"?

Answer (score 1):

C1 is shorted(both leads shorted) so you can exclude it for this model. Whats left is C2.. which is the answer..

Comment: But when C2 is balanced, won't the current start to charge C1.

Comment: @PetarVelkov C1 is *shorted*. It can't hold any charge.

Comment: @PetarVelkov No and I'm not sure what you mean by "balanced".

Comment: I mean charged.

Comment: As said, the current takes the way through the wire bypassing C1. If a component is shortened like this, you can always remove the component because it plays no role.

Comment: Its shorted, you cant charge it. If both leads are on the same "wire" then they have the "same" potential/voltage. How can it have any charge if the leads have the same voltage?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, current always prefers low resistance path. And hence, it will avoid capacitor C1 as it's shorted. So, equivalent capacitance of the circuit is C2.

Comment: No. Current does NOT "prefer" a low resistance path. Current will divide in the inverse ratio of the resistances of the available paths. Where the paths are substantially different in impedance or resistance the majority of current will take the lower Z or R path. ONLY in this special case where R_ideal_wire = 0.00000000000000000000 Ohms will ALL the current go via the low resistance path.

Comment: Yup. That's right. But, considering question asker is new guy, I tried to tell him this in simple language.